# Need help optimizing a MySQL query - JOINs not using the correct indexes

Tags: optimization, mysql, query-optimization

I have this query below that I've rewritten a dozen different ways, yet I am unable to get it optimized and loaded in under 8 seconds.  If I can get it to 2s, that would be good.  1s or less would be optimal.

This query retrieves a list of books that are currently available for sale or trade, and performs a bit of filtering.  This query takes about 9-10 seconds.

```
SELECT
listing.for_sale,
listing.for_trade,
MIN(listing.price) AS from_price,
MAX(listing.price) AS to_price,
IF (NOW() > CONVERT_TZ(listing.date_sale_expiration, '+00:00', '-7:00'), 1, 0) AS expired,

COUNT(listing.book_id) AS 'listing_count',
book.id AS 'book_id',
book.title AS 'book_title',
book.date_released AS 'date_released',
book.publisher AS 'publisher',
book.photo_cover AS 'photo_cover',

publisher.name AS 'publisher_name',

COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM listing l1 WHERE l1.book_id = book.id AND l1.status IN ('in_active_deal', 'complete')), 0) AS 'number_sold',
(SELECT 1 FROM listing l2 WHERE l2.status = 'available' AND l2.book_id = book.id AND l2.member_id = 1234 LIMIT 1) AS 'hasListing',
(SELECT 1 FROM wishlist w1 WHERE w1.book_id = book.id AND w1.member_id = 1234 LIMIT 1) AS 'hasWishlist'

FROM listing

INNER JOIN member ON
listing.member_id = member.id
AND member.transaction_limit <> 0
AND member.banned <> 1
AND member.date_last_login > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 120 DAY)

INNER JOIN book ON
listing.book_id = book.id
AND book.released = 1

INNER JOIN publisher ON
book.publisher_id = publisher.id

WHERE
listing.type = 'book'
AND listing.status = 'available'
AND (listing.for_trade = 1 OR (listing.for_sale = 1 AND NOW() < COALESCE(CONVERT_TZ(listing.date_sale_expiration, '+00:00', '-7:00'), 0)))
AND (
  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM listing l3 LEFT JOIN book b ON l3.book_id = b.id WHERE l3.member_id = 1234 AND b.publisher_id = book.publisher_id AND l3.status = 'available' AND l3.type = 'book' AND (l3.for_trade = 1 OR (l3.for_sale = 1 AND NOW() < COALESCE(CONVERT_TZ(l3.date_sale_expiration, '+00:00', '-7:00'), 0))) LIMIT 1)
  OR member.publisher_only <> 1
  OR member.id = 1234
)
AND (
  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM wishlist w WHERE w.member_id = member.id AND w.type = 'book' AND (w.type, w.book_id) IN (SELECT l4.type, l4.book_id FROM listing l4 WHERE 1234 = l4.member_id AND l4.status = 'available' AND (l4.for_trade = 1 OR (l4.for_sale = 1 AND NOW() < COALESCE(DATE_SUB(l4.date_sale_expiration, INTERVAL 7 HOUR), 0)))) LIMIT 1)
  OR member.wishlist_only <> 1
  OR member.id = 1234
)

GROUP BY
book.id

ORDER BY
book.date_released DESC

LIMIT 30;
```

These are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `listing` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `member_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('book','audiobook','accessory') NOT NULL,
  `book_id` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
  `audiobook_id` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
  `accessory_id` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_sale_expiration` datetime default NULL,
  `status` enum('available','in_active_deal','complete','deleted') NOT NULL default 'available',
  `for_sale` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `for_trade` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `price` decimal(10,2) default NULL,
  `condition` tinyint(1) unsigned default NULL,
  `notes` varchar(255) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `ix_accessory` (`accessory_id`,`member_id`,`type`,`status`),
  KEY `ix_book` (`book_id`,`member_id`,`type`,`status`),
  KEY `ix_member` (`member_id`,`status`,`date_created`),
  KEY `ix_audiobook` (`audiobook_id`,`member_id`,`type`,`status`),
  KEY `ix_status` (`status`,`accessory_id`,`for_trade`,`member_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=281724 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `member` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `email` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `screen_name` varchar(25) default NULL,
  `date_last_login` datetime default NULL,
  `wishlist_only` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '1',
  `platform_only` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `transaction_limit` smallint(6) NOT NULL default '5',
  `banned` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `notes` text,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `ix_email` (`email`),
  KEY `ix_screen_name` (`screen_name`),
  KEY `ix_transaction_limit` (`transaction_limit`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=50842 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `publisher` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `date_updated` datetime default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `ix_name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=129 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `book` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `publisher_id` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `keywords` varchar(200) default NULL,
  `date_released` varchar(10) default NULL,
  `genre` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `subgenre` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `author` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `date_updated` datetime default NULL,
  `photo_cover` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `weight_oz` decimal(7,2) default NULL,
  `released` tinyint(2) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `ix_genre` (`genre`),
  KEY `ix_name` (`name`),
  KEY `ix_released` (`released`,`date_released`),
  KEY `ix_keywords` (`keywords`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=87329 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `wishlist` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `member_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('book','audiobook','accessory') NOT NULL,
  `book_id` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
  `audiobook_id` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
  `accessory_id` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `ix_accessory` (`accessory_id`,`member_id`,`type`),
  KEY `ix_book` (`book_id`,`member_id`,`type`),
  KEY `ix_member_accessory` (`member_id`,`accessory_id`),
  KEY `ix_member_date_created` (`member_id`,`date_created`),
  KEY `ix_member_book` (`member_id`,`book_id`),
  KEY `ix_member_audiobook` (`member_id`,`audiobook_id`),
  KEY `ix_audiobook` (`audiobook_id`,`member_id`,`type`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=241886 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

And here is the result when I run EXPLAIN:

```
+----+--------------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+---------+------------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table     | type           | possible_keys                                                                         | key                  | key_len | ref                                | rows  | Extra                                        |
+----+--------------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+---------+------------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | member    | range          | PRIMARY,ix_transaction_limit                                                          | ix_transaction_limit | 2       | NULL                               | 19617 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | listing   | ref            | ix_game,ix_member,ix_status                                                           | ix_member            | 5       | live_database001.member.id,const   |     7 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | book      | eq_ref         | PRIMARY,ix_released                                                                   | PRIMARY              | 4       | live_database001.listing.book_id   |     1 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | publisher | eq_ref         | PRIMARY                                                                               | PRIMARY              | 4       | live_database001.book.publisher_id |     1 |                                              |
|  6 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | w         | ref            | ix_member_accessory,ix_member_date_created,ix_member_book,ix_member_publisher         | ix_member_accessory  | 4       | live_database001.member.id         |     6 | Using where                                  |
|  7 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | l4        | index_subquery | ix_book,ix_member,ix_status                                                           | ix_book              | 11      | func,const,func,const              |     1 | Using where                                  |
|  5 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | l3        | ref            | ix_book,ix_member,ix_status                                                           | ix_member            | 5       | const,const                        |    63 | Using where                                  |
|  5 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | b         | eq_ref         | PRIMARY                                                                               | PRIMARY              | 4       | live_database001.l3.book_id        |     1 | Using where                                  |
|  4 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | w1        | ref            | ix_book,ix_member_accessory,ix_member_date_created,ix_member_game,ix_member_publisher | ix_book              | 9       | func,const                         |     1 | Using where; Using index                     |
|  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | l2        | ref            | ix_book,ix_member,ix_status                                                           | ix_book              | 9       | func,const                         |     1 | Using where; Using index                     |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | l1        | ref            | ix_book,ix_status                                                                     | ix_book              | 5       | func                               |    10 | Using where; Using index                     |
+----+--------------------+-----------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+---------+------------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
```

**This brings me to a couple questions:**
1. The member table is using `ix_transaction_limit`, and as a result is searching through 19k+ rows.  Since I am specifying a `member.id`, shouldn't this be using `PRIMARY` and shouldn't the `rows` be 1?  How can I fix this?
2. How does the `key_len` affect the performance?
3. I've seen other complex queries which dealt with 100's of millions of rows take less time. How is it that only 19k rows are taking so long?

*(I'm still very green with MySQL Optimization, so I'd really love to understand the how's & why's)*

Any suggestions small or big is greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: It doesn't appear that you're querying for one particular member above - 1234 appears a few times, but the main `WHERE` doesn't restrict to just this member.  The more complex the query, the more trouble the optimizer is going to have figuring out the optimal approach to tackling it.  Using functions against fields (e.g. `COALESCE(CONVERT_TZ(...` is not going to help matters.

I would suggest breaking this query down into several and use temporary tables - it's way too complex as it stands.

Comment: Cuando averigües donde está, salúdalo de mi parte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After dropping the index on the member table, I was still having the same problems. In fact, that made it even worse.  So my ultimate solution was to completely re-write the query from scratch.

And consequently, changing the order in the conditionals made a big difference as well. So moving the `and member_id = 1234` and the `and wishlish_only <> 1` up above the subquery was a huge improvement.

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what transaction limit does but at a guess it seems like a strange choice to have an index on. What might help is an index on date_last_login. At the moment the query is filtering member and then joining listing to it - ie. its going through all the member records with the appropriate transaction limit and using the member id to find the listing.

Comment: transaction limit is a number that is set for limiting the number of transactions that can be made.  Mostly for fraud purposes so stolen CC's can't make hundreds of purchases within a certain amount of time.  But this number can change, depending on if a user becomes validated, etc.